# VBA - Do While Loop returns Dir <Invalid procedure call or argument>

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, do-while

I am running a loop through a folder in order to get the complete filename address (folders address + file name and extension).

I am using the following, but at some point the Dir value is `<Invalid procedure call or argument>`

```
recsFolder = Functions.GetFolder("C:\")
recfile = recsFolder & "\" & Dir(recsFolder & "\*.rec*")
Do While Len(recfile) > 0
   recfile = recsFolder & "\" & Dir
Loop
```

The error is thrown before the loop as completed reading all the files.

EDIT: another approach and Dir is changing everytime I press F8

```
If Right(recsFolder, 1) <> "\" Then recsFolder = recsFolder & "\"
numFiles = 0
recfile = Dir(recsFolder)
While recfile <> ""
    numFiles = numFiles + 1
    recfile = Dir()
Wend
```

I am trying this latest approach and I get the same error. The problem is that when I run the code line by line (F8) I can see that the Dir value changes everytime a new line of code is run inside the While.

Comment: Why not add a `debug.print` statement for each recfile to see where the job fails? Alternatively you could add an `on error Goto`  and perhaps `resume next`. However, I'd recommend finding where the problem is first!

Comment: It tells tells the same "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument."

Comment: @MiguelH Please see the edited question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of DIR, how about this:

```
' enable Tools->References, Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub Test()
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fldr As Folder

    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\test")
    HandleFolder fldr
End Sub


Sub HandleFolder(fldr As Folder)
    Dim f As File
    Dim subFldr As Folder

    ' loop thru files in this folder
    For Each f In fldr.Files
        Debug.Print f.Path
    Next

    ' loop thru subfolders
    For Each subFldr In fldr.SubFolders
        HandleFolder subFldr
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

IDK it it helps but this is a pretty solid frame

```
 path = "yourpath" & "\"
 Filename = Dir(path & "*.fileextension")

 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
     'some code
     Filename = Dir
 Loop
```

Comment: I'm getting an erro on the second passage in filename= Dir .