# Error "Invalid procedure call or argument" doing a Dir Loop

Tags: excel, vba, directory, runtime-error

I get this error when looping through files

> "Invalid procedure call or argument"

The below code should scan through a folder, open the first file, modify it, then go to the next excel and do the same again. The problem is that it does not recognize any other file in the folder (except the first file) and returns the above error. See below the code:

```
xExcelFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.xls*")
Do While xExcelFile <> ""
    'more code
     xExcelFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: The part of the code you provided is running for me. At which line do you get the error _"Invalid procedure call or argument"_. Ath the line _xExcelFile = Dir_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - Do While Loop returns Dir <Invalid procedure call or argument>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354336/vba-do-while-loop-returns-dir-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument)

Comment: Do you have this running inside another loop which also uses `Dir()` ?  That's not supported.

Comment: Yes thanks guys, Its because I had another function with Dir()

Comment: This question needs a proper [mcve] to be answerable without speculations

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna answer myself, I have a duplicate Dir() in my macro.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if you have "Dir" as a watches (to monitor it's value), as this is going to increment the value at each debug step