# Function Dir() not working as excepted : Error Code 5 : Invalid argument or procedure call

Tags: excel, vba, file, pdf, path

I'm trying to set a macro which will moove file from a certain folder to another one, If this file already exists then it will display a message box if a file from an other folder already exist in a folder. Here is the problem..

I think the first error is here :

`StrFile = Dir`
Here is the error it display me the error code : 5 Invalid argument or procedure call
And the excepted output of this line code is to go to next file in order to browse all my .Pdf file one per one

```vb
Sub MooveFile()

Dim filepath As String
Dim currfile As String
Dim NomFichier As String
Dim Direction As String
Dim StrFile As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFileName As String, DestinFileName As String



    StrFile = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "*.PDF")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Direction = Split(StrFile, " ")(0)
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")


    SourceFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & StrFile


         Set FoundRange = Sheets("Path").Cells.Find(what:=Direction, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If FoundRange Is Nothing Then 'Here is the test if the folder exist : WORKING
            On Error Resume Next
            MkDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Direction
            DestinFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Direction & "\" & StrFile
            FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileName

            Else 'If Folder exist : WORKING

                DestinFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Direction & "\" & StrFile
                    If Dir(SourceFileName) <> "" Then 'IF File exist then display the message box : WORKING
                        Select Case MsgBox("le fichier" & SourceFileName & "existe déjà voulez-vous le remplacer", vbAbortRetryIgnore)

                        Case vbAbort
                        ' Cancel the operation.
                        MsgBox "Operation canceled"

                        Case vbRetry
                        ' Continue the Do loop to try again.
                        FSO.DeleteFile DestinFileName, True

                        FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileName

                        Case vbIgnore
                        ' Take a default action.
                        GoTo nextline

                        End Select

                    Else
                        FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileName
                    End If


                'FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileName

            End If

nextline:
        StrFile = Dir 'This line code is not working at : Error code 5 :Invalid argument or procedure call 
    Loop 'Fin Boucle

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Did I miss something here ? I already tried `StrFile = Dir()`

Comment: @JvdV sure it is, this string contains the filename

Comment: I can't replicate the error unfortunately :(. Here is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354336/vba-do-while-loop-returns-dir-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument) question though.

Comment: @JvdV For you this work ? because its working into 1 folder but this don't into an other one ... I don't understand. Maybe you can help me by upvote I am stuck..

Comment: I'm sorry I have misunderstood the question. I was trying to debug the part  `StrFile = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "*.PDF")`

Comment: oh okay @jvdV the error is at the end of the macro maybe because i use Dir so many time ? ..

Comment: Whatever the code is meant to do it will stop working once the `Dir(SourceFileName) <> ""` is reached. This will break `Do While` loop - `Dir` at the end of this loop will repeat the search for `SourceFileName` not the original one.

Comment: Thanks @BrakNicku thats a mistake it must be `If Dir(StrFile) <> ""` but this didn't solve the error i will edit my issue

Comment: You `Dir` 2 files. `Dir` is ment to return the names of all file matching the initial pattern, while you issue another `Dir` within the loop. Try to reorganize the loop like collecting matching filenames to a collection and then in a subsequent loop do the further processings.

Comment: So do you know a different way to check if a file exists in an other folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `Dir` when you are creating a FileSystemObject?

Although (in my experience) it is slower it is far more robust.

For a start, don't create it as an Object.  Put a reference to `Windows.Scripting` then

```
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
set FSO= New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

Apart from anything else, it will give you the Intellisense which makes life easier.

You can then check for a file/folder with

```
If FSO.FileExists(myFile) Then
If FSO.FolderExists(myFolder) Then
```

And start to use collections such as

```
Dim fi As Scripting.File
For Each fi In FSO.GetFolder(myFolder).Files
Next
```

[Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object)

Comment: thanks for your time, By the way what should return : `FSO.FileExists(myFile)` does it return a boolean ?

Comment: Yes.  You can use `If FSO.FileExists(myFile) Then` or `If FSO.FileExists(myFile) = True Then`, depending on your style preference.  They are exactly the same.