# Code runs fine but error when stepping through

Tags: vba

Update: I have been directed to a solution here [VBA - Do While Loop returns Dir <Invalid procedure call or argument>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354336/vba-do-while-loop-returns-dir-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument)

The code below is to loop through a folder selected by the user and list the files within.

It works fine when writing to a MsgBox or Debug.Print via F5 but it results in a Run Time Error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument" when trying to step through it and breaks at `FileToList = Dir`.

When I observe the watch window for Dir and FileToList, Dir gets to "" before FileToList even gets to the third file in the folder.  Every press of F8 moving through the loop causes the Dir value to change before a full loop cycle.

```
Sub Loop_Inside_Folder()
 
Dim FileDir As String
Dim FileToList As String
 
 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Please select a folder"
    .ButtonName = "Pick Folder"
    If .Show = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing was selected"
        Exit Sub
    Else
    'Folder path
        FileDir = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End If
 End With
 
 'Get first matching file name
 FileToList = Dir(FileDir & "*xlsm")
 
 Do Until FileToList = ""
    
    'Debug.Print FileToList
    FileToList = Dir
 Loop
 
End Sub
```

To test it further, I included 5 lines of:

```
FiletoList = Dir(FileDir & "*.xls*")
FiletoList = Dir(FileDir & "*.xls*")
FiletoList = Dir(FileDir & "*.xls*")
FiletoList = Dir(FileDir & "*.xls*")
FiletoList = Dir(FileDir & "*.xls*")
FiletoList = Dir(FileDir & "*.xls*")
```

The values at each step were:

```
Dir : "File 2.xlsx"

FileToList : "File 1.xlsx"
```

So it would appear that when stepping through, FileToList = Dir isn't working properly.  It's as though Dir can't match FileToList and so it goes to the next available file.

I am not sure if it's something with my local enviroment or not?  Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see update with Stack Overflow link at top of initial post.